# morphism between short exact sequences of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, category-theory, exact-sequence

I have recently been trying to learn some linear algebra, and have been following the book: Elements of Linear and Multilinear Algebra by John M. Erdman. The book states a theorem and has left the proof as an exercise to the reader. However, I don't even know how to start begining to prove the theorem. The theorem is as follows.

> Consider the following diagram in the category of vector spaces and linear maps.
> $\require{AMScd}$
> \begin{CD}
> 0@>>>U@>j>>V@>k>>W@>>>0\\
> @.@VfVV@VVgV@VVhV\\
> 0@>>>U'@>>j'>V'@>>k'>W'@>>>0
> \end{CD}
> If the rows are exact and the left square commutes, then there exists a unique linear map $h:W\rightarrow W'$ that makes the right square commute.

I realise that $j$ and $j'$ are both injective and similarly that $k$ and $k'$ are both surjective, but I am unsure how to use this information to show that $h$ exists.

Comment: I did notice that since $j'\circ f=g\circ j$ and $h\circ k=k'\circ g$ it must follow that $h\circ k\circ j=k'\circ g\circ j=k'\circ j'\circ f$. But I have never really gotten father than that

Comment: Ooops, I didn't notice the missing prime, it has been added now. I would now that for any $w\in W$ there exists atleast one $v\in V$ such that $k(v)=w$ as $k$ is surjective, but I don't see what I could do with that information.

Comment: Good point! Now, what must your -still to be defined- $h(w)$ be equal to, in terms of such a $v,$ for the diagram to commute? (After that, you will have to check that this $h(w)$ is in fact independent from your choice of $v$.) I am sure you will find. Once you have, please feel free to [edit the solution as an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: I am still a bit unsure how to proceed after noting that $h(w)=h(k(v))$. I don't see how I could use this to show that $h(k(v))=k'(g(v))$.

Comment: You don't show it. It is part of your hypothesis (look at your first comment above). And it is the reason why you "noted" that $h(w)$ must be *defined* as equal to $h(k(v)).$

Comment: I don't really see how to go on with the proof. I am sure there's something really obvious that I'm just missing, but I just don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0):

A map $h:W\to W'$ satisfies $h\circ k=k'\circ g$ iff for every $w\in W,$ written $k(v)$ for some $v\in V$ (by surjectivity of $k$), we have $h(w)=k'(g(v)).$ This proves the uniqueness of the solution $h$ if any.

Let us now prove this existence, i.e. prove that the previous condition
$$w=k(v)\implies h(w)=k'(g(v))$$
defines $h$ non-ambiguously, and that such an $h$ is linear.

- the definition is non-ambiguous because if $k(v')=k(v)$ then $k'(g(v'))=k'(g(v)),$ since the difference is $(k'\circ g)(v'-v)=(h\circ k)(v'-v)=h(0)=0.$
- the linearity of $h$ follows easily from (again) the linearity of $k$ and $k'\circ g.$

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer, it was very helpful.

Comment: Cheers! https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers My only regret is not having succeded in letting you found it yourself.

Comment: It's okay. I see in hindsight that my problem was trying to use the other morphisms to somehow construct $h$ instead of seeing if the conditions required of $h$ unambiguosly defined a morphism.